# I want command + f to always search file in vscode regardless of focus

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

[image]

I do not want this green box to appear when pressing command + f in vscode and the sidebar is focused. i want command + f to always enable search within the file. this green box is useless to me because its functionality already provided by the superior command palette (command + p)

`"workbench.list.defaultFindMode"` seems to be the control for it, but valid values for this are only  'filter' and 'highlight', no way to get rid of it.

Version: 1.70.2

help?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, finally found it.
remove the command + f keybinding from `list.find`